# Write a quadratic equation in the form y=Ax^2 + Bx +C?

Tags: quadratics

the question is to turn this question {1/4} double root to standard form.

What i got is x = 1/4, x= 1/4 
once you multiply them you get x^2 -1/2x -1/16 I think not sure if I'm correct

and thanks to who ever it is that edits my question...i don't know how to write it in a proper way and am learning but thanks

Comment: Not even addressing the fact that I have no idea what you're asking here, [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) will explain how to format your math.  It's not that hard.  For instance, to make x^2 -1/2x -1/16 look nicer, just throw a `$` in front of and after it to get $x^2 -1/2x -1/16$.  Or even better, use `$x^2 - \frac {1}{2}x - \frac {1}{16}$` to get $x^2 - \frac {1}{2}x - \frac {1}{16}$ or `$x^2 - \dfrac {1}{2}x - \dfrac {1}{16}$` to get $x^2 - \dfrac {1}{2}x - \dfrac {1}{16}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct.
For any two roots
$a$ and $b$,
the quadratic with those roots
is
$0
=(x-a)(x-b)
=x^2-(a+b)x + ab
$.

If
$a = b = \frac14$,
the quadratic is
$x^2-(\frac14+\frac14)x+\frac14\cdot \frac14
=x^2-\frac12x+\frac1{16}
$.